# How to select one row from ienumerable in asp.net mvc view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I have a asp.net mvc view that has a model of type IEnumerable. Within this view has a table with data being passed to it. My goal is to show a modal with all the details of that specific element when that row is clicked. At the moment, the model being passed to the view contains all the information that is being displayed and the information fields that should be shown on the modal as well.

```
@model IEnumerable<TestApplication.DataModels.PackageDetails>

    <div class="table-responsive " style="height: 300px">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ref_Num)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer_Name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Package_Description)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Package_Authorization_Date)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Package_Arrival_Date)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Package_Total)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Percentage_Due_Now)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pending_Balance)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateDifference)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SendReminder)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style=" font-style:italic; color:#000066; text-decoration: underline;">
                            <span class="show-package-details" data-id="@item.Ref_Num"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal" style="cursor: pointer;">@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Ref_Num)</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px; ">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer_Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Package_Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Package_Authorization_Date)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Package_Arrival_Date)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Package_Total)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Percentage_Due_Now)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pending_Balance)
                        </td>
                        @if ((item.DateDifference < 5) && (item.DateDifference > 0))
                        {
                            <td style="color: #ff0000;">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateDifference)
                            </td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateDifference)
                            </td>

                        }
                        <td>
                            @if (item.DateDifference > 0)
                            {
                                <button id="btnSendReminder" type="button" class="btn btn-light" style="font-size : 10px; width: 100%; height: 20%;">
                                    Send
                                </button>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <button id="btnSendReminder" type="button" class="btn btn-light" disabled style="font-size : 10px; width: 100%; height: 20%;">
                                    Send
                                </button>
                            }

                        </td>
                    </tr>




                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>



@*Modal For Details*@
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1"
         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="container-fluid">


                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    REFERENCE NUMBER: 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    RESERVED ON:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    PAID AMOUNT:
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    CUSTOMER NAME:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    ARRIVAL DATE:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    PENDING BALANCE:
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:

                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    PACKAGE TOTAL:
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    OFFER EXPIRES ON:
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    PACKAGE DETAILS: 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    BALANCE TO BE PAID BY: <div class="balancepaid">    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>




                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Edit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

for clarification, the package details model has the following properties

```
  public string Ref_Num { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Customer_Name { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "PACKAGE DESCRIPTION")]
        public string Package_Description { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "RESERVED ON")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Package_Authorization_Date { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "ARRIVAL DATE")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Package_Arrival_Date { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "TOTAL AMOUNT")]
        public decimal Package_Total { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "PAID AMOUNT")]
        public decimal Percentage_Due_Now { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "PENDING BALANCE")]
        public decimal Pending_Balance { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "DAYS PENDING")]
        public int DateDifference { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "SEND REMINDER")]
        public bool SendReminder { set; get; }


//additional fields to be shown only on modal 
        public string Package_EMailAddress { set; get; }
        public string Package_Detail { set; get; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Expire_Date { set; get; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Pay_Pending_Balance_By { set; get; }
```

Comment: I don't see a clear question here. If you are trying to access an element of `IEnumerable` with an index -- you can't. You can construct List with the IEnumerable then use the indexer. You can also increment a running index yourself as you run through the `foreach` loop.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think I know what you want - instead of the typical Details link that takes you to a new View, you want a modal to pop up. What have you tried so far?

I haven't used modals too much but I expect you'll need Javascript and some way to pass the values of each record (you can select an element for an IEnumerable with ElementAt(i)).

Comment: How Do I determine which row was clicked and then select that row of information from the IEnumerable list and then display that row in the html modal div

Comment: I tried something out myself and implementing modals isn't as trivial as, for example, a 'Details' View. See harmath's answer - that's the way to go but it seems like a lot of effort just for modals. Unless you pre-generate modals for all the results, hide them, and then show on click, you'll need to do a call to the server like in the answer. What's happening there, in short, is that a unique identifier for the record is passed to a JS function, which makes an AJAX call to an action (you'll need to create one in the controller) that sends the single record back to be processed into a modal.

Comment: thanks, I knew that method but I thought there was some workaround to shorten the code. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a button in your first list.

```
 <th>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default showmodal" id="@item.Ref_Num">Show Modal</button>  
 </th>
```

...and add this JavaScript code.

```
 $("document").ready(function () {

        $('.showmodal').on('click', function () {
            var Id=this.value;
            getAjaxRequest(Id,fillDOMelements);
        });
    });
 function fillDOMelements(yourObj)
    {
        if(typeof yourObj!=null && typeof yourObj!==undefined)
        {
            //your modal fields
            $("[name='modal_Customer_Name']").val(yourObj.Customer_Name);
            $("[name='modal_Package_Description']").val(yourObj.Package_Description);
            ....
        }
    }
 function getAjaxRequest(id,callbackFunction)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/Action",
            data: "{'Id' : "+id+"}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                callbackFunction(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: maybe check this [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) doc first.

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxqd4npb/). It has the source code generated from the Razor View code below. It uses DOM traversal to get the values you need for a given row.

Note the `onclick="blah(this)"` for the span element that reveals the modal.

Note the JS function `function blah(x)` that grabs its rows values and replaces certain parts of the modal template when it's invoked.

Hopefully this gives you an idea of what you need to do. You're still writing code but you avoid a call to the server.

Another note there's a chance this new onclick event may clash with the existing modal events. I'm not certain on the order of things so you'll have to see how it goes.

Last note, I don't recommend this. I might look at Razor components instead but that's a whole other thing.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <table class="table table-striped mt-4">
            <tr style="background-color:#004A88;color:white;">
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Procedure</th>
                <th scope="col">Method</th>
                <th scope="col">All Staff</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Description</td>
                    <td>@item.Procedure</td>
                    <td>@item.Method</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AllRequired)</td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="span@(item.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="blah(this)">Show Modal @item.Id</span> |
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>

        function blah(x) {
            var parentrow = x.parentElement.parentElement;
            var myvalue = parentrow.children[0].innerText;
            var myvalue2 = parentrow.children[1].innerText;
            $(".modal-title").text(myvalue);
            $(".modal-body").text(myvalue2);
        }
    </script>
}
```